# WinRT C# - HttpRequestException: error 500

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to port my WP8 application to a Windows Store App and I'm getting an HttpRequestException when performing the getStringAsync of the HttpClient.

Here is the code snippet giving me the issue:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(new Uri("http://www.psnapi.com.ar/ps3/api/psn.asmx/getPSNID?sPSNID=philippemexes", UriKind.Absolute));
```

and here is the complete exception message:

> HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
>   I have to said that the indicated URL works in the browser and the exactly same code works properly in the Windows Phone project too.

Does anyone knows which could be a possible solution to get the desired xml to a string and why is this working for Windows Phone and not for a WinRT app?

Thank you very much
Stefano

Comment: good to check the app manifest, capabilities tab that internet(client) is checked. secondly, try putting another url here say 'www.google.com' and see if that works?

Comment: thanks for your reply, Internet(client) capability was already enabled, I tried to enable Internet(client & server) and Private networks but unfortunately it didn't work. Changing the url instead worked...so the problem must be accessing that url, but it's very strange that it's currently working in windows phone

Comment: Well, your code crashed the server.  If you want to find out why then you should not ask us, you should ask the server owner.  He can look in the server log to see what exactly went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/home) is your friend!

Appears that service isn't too happy about being called when there's not a user-agent string passed in the request headers.  Try adding:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "blah blah blah");
```

between your two lines of code.  There's nothing magic in the `blah blah blah` part :), and it seems to work with your service, but who knows what, if any, interpretation the service is making of the UA string.