# ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden' HttpResponseMessage winrt

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, asynchttpclient

i'm getting this error :ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden' in the response variable:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

besides i used it with an other url and it works fine ! any ideas please?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your uri.  Hard to tell without knowing the uri.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

Comment: But the uri works very well with webclient in wp7!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000863/winrt-c-sharp-httprequestexception-error-500/16006789#16006789 - perhaps the server is denying the request because it's not coming in with a User-Agent?