# How to call API URL windows 8 C#

Tags: windows-8

I am new to windows 8. I want to call api url and the response will be return in terms of json. My Question is how to call below api url in my windows 8 code with c#.

API URL: http://scwin8dashboard.cloudapp.net/shell/~/analytics/reports/reports.ashx?fff=0&report=CampaignCategoriesOverview&languages=&sites=&startDate=20080101&endDate=20121114&addLastModified=true

please help

Answer (score 0):

```
var uri = "http://scwin8dashboard.cloudapp.net/shell/~/analytics/reports/reports.ashx?fff=0&report=CampaignCategoriesOverview&languages=&sites=&startDate=20080101&endDate=20121114&addLastModified=true";
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
var parser = JsonObject.Parse(response);
```

For more informations about Http requests see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781239.aspx).

For JSON related classes see the [Windows.Data.Json namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.data.json.aspx).

Comment: When I used this code I am getting this error {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: where am I going wrong

Comment: pls any one help with the above problem

Comment: this means the server is having some issues. when you try the url in browser also - you see error page. need to contact or debug server

Comment: when I see the url in browser I am getting date URL: http://scwin8dashboard.cloudapp.net/shell/~/analytics/reports/reports.ashx?fff=0&report=CampaignCategoriesOverview&languages=&sites=&startDate=20080101&endDate=20121114&addLastModified=true    should be some other problem but I couldn't trigger it out.

Comment: take a look at this thread to see if it applies in your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000863/winrt-c-sharp-httprequestexception-error-500/16006789#16006789